# .NET Core and JSON Web Tokens, still need Owin?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, owin, asp.net-core-webapi

first time doing this in .net core, I've set up JWT auth / ASP Identity database using these tutorials, both of which are quite good:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH4GhmTPf68

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEU9SDmIvVY

However, when I set this up a few years ago, I used OWin. I'm having trouble finding resources on .Net Core using both JWT and Owin. Is JWT secure by itself in .Net Core or do we still need Owin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No. At .net core, there is no need to set up OWIN manually as you are using JWT token.

There is no reason to implement OWIN like the old days at WebAPI 2.
Inside net.core Startup file, you will notice a Configure function that looks similar like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

You will now Configure the services inside this file and registering the authentication services inside this file.
Here is a good resource that I used when I'm upgrading my web app from Web API 2 to .NET core 2 for my authentication server.

https://andrewlock.net/a-look-behind-the-jwt-bearer-authentication-middleware-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling this was the case but found it very difficult to verify. Your info and link is most appreciated.